# Getting datetime string with multiple format in string

Tags: c#

How to get datetime string with multiple format in string?
Example: "abc 14/01/2020 cde", "12:11 14/01/2020 abcde", "abcde 12:11 14-01-2020"
Help me. Thanks you!

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you asking here?

Comment: Does `abc`, `cde`, etc represent random text in the string?  The dates presumably are in a variety of formats too...

Comment: abc, cde... represent random text in the string and i want focus all case format of datetime can happen.

Comment: @ChangNgokTB This is hard to achieve if the text is completely freeform with dates in differing formats randomly embedded inside it.  Have you got a full list of all the different date formats that can be present?

Comment: show your work - the relevant code snippet in your attempt to serialize\parse, and exception.  some of these formats are not known datetime specifications to me.  Where is this data stored? in a file?

Comment: Do you mean you want to parse all datetimes in a string, regardless of format or other noise? Can you tell me what date 01/08/2020 represents (you can rearrange it to yyyy-MM-dd format to give your answer)?

Comment: @John I recognize the point you're making, but it is semantical - there is a default handling for that `DateTime.Parse("01/08/2020")` will return January 8th 2020 12am.  obviously it's erroneous but it's a deferred user\system input logic handling scenario.

Comment: thanks so much. ít can: dd/MM/yyyy or HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy or HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy... and more. I think so hard

Comment: I've created a regex-based attempt, rather than using the built-in DateTime parsing as this would still need data preparation before it could be used. I hope it's a good starting point for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how robust this approach will be, but I would perhaps a regular expression:

```
((?<hr>\d{2}):(?<min>\d{2}) )?(?<day>\d{1,2})([^\d])(?<month>\d{1,2})\2(?<year>\d{4})
```

I'll break it down and explain what each part does:

```
* ((?<hr>\d{2}):(?<min>\d{2}) )? - this part will capture the leading time values
- We require \d{2} for each value, which means two digits. For hour and minutes, we wrap this in a named capture group: (?<hr>\d{2}) and (?<min>\d{2})
- We wrap this in another capture group to add the : and the trailing space, and then top it off with a ? to make the whole group optional.

* (?<day>\d{1,2})([^\d])(?<month>\d{1,2})\2(?<year>\d{4}) - this part will capture the day, month, and year of the date with any separator between (provided the separator isn't a number).
- For day and month we require 1 or 2 digits (\d{1,2}) and for year we require 4 digits (\d{4}).
- For the separator, we have a negative match set which will match any character except those in the set: ([\d])
- We've wrapped the separator in a capture group, so that we can reference it between month and year using \2 (its capture group number).
  This ensures that a date like 14/02-2020 wouldn't be valid, but 14/02/2020 or 14-02-2020 will be.
```

Now on the C# side, we can create a `Regex` entity for matching:

```
var matcher = new Regex(@"((?<hr>\d{2}):(?<min>\d{2}) )?(?<day>\d{1,2})([^\d])(?<month>\d{1,2})\2(?<year>\d{4})");
```

Then we can test a given string for a match and construct a date from it:

```
Match m = matcher.Match(str);
if (m.Success)
{
    int hr = 0;
    int min = 0;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups["hr"].Value) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups["min"].Value))
    {
        hr = int.Parse(m.Groups["hr"].Value);
        min = int.Parse(m.Groups["min"].Value);
    }

    int day = int.Parse(m.Groups["day"].Value);
    int month = int.Parse(m.Groups["month"].Value);
    int year = int.Parse(m.Groups["year"].Value);

    // Create a date with type DateTimeKind.Local
    // more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimekind?view=net-5.0
    var date = new DateTime(year, month, day, hr, min, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);     
}
else
{
    // no match
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/CWPS18571)

You might need to adjust the regular expression if you also need other formats, but hopefully this is a good starting point for you.